# CSS: Why block element wrap around floating element

Tags: css, layout

See example at http://jsfiddle.net/w1xhpp2c/. I don't understand why div.b is wrapped around the float element. I always thought that only inline element could wrap float elements, while block elements will not.

```
.wrap{
        width: 500px;
    }
    .a{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;

    }
    .b{
        background-color:#eee;
        width:500px;
    }

<div class="wrap">

        <div class="a">
            a<br/>
            a<br/>
        </div>

        <div class="b">
             b<br/>
             b<br/>
             b<br/>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block boxes flow under floating elements. [CSS 2.1 spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float didn’t
>   exist

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want this to happen, you need to clear your float:

```
.wrap{
        width: 500px;
        overflow: none;
    }
    .a{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;

    }
    .b{
        background-color:#eee;
        width:500px;
        clear: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this would be better, especially the control of the placing gets better.
http://jsfiddle.net/w1xhpp2c/1/

```
    .wrap{
        width: 500px;
        float:left;
    }
    .a{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;

    }
    .b{
        float:right;
        background-color:#eee;
        width:300px;
    }
```

In short let the wrapper also float and inside let the left elements float left and the right ones right.