# Div (display: block) not respecting other floated divs

Tags: css

Example: https://jsbin.com/duloyuvoqu/edit?html,css,js,output

As you can see in the example when it's just a normal floated div to the right with just text, the text acts normally and wraps around the floated item.

When you toggle the panel on the panel goes across the floated div.

I know of a couple of ways to fix it, you can add: `display: table|flex|grid;` any of those 3 options will fix it but the main question is why does `block` act this way and is there a way to make it behave like `table|flex|grid`?

Comment: I'm confused on what is the issue, and what this means, "When you toggle the panel on the panel goes across the floated div."

Comment: @RobScott if you check the example, there is a toggle panel button. When the panel is there, it goes under the floated item. I added the toggle just so you could see it works normally when there are just `<p>`'s

Comment: Soooo, do you want the toggled panel to wrap around the floated `div` in the same way that the text does?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Basically, yea. I know how to do that, you can add `display: table;` and it fixes it. It was more just a curious question as to why the `<div>` acts differently to the `<p>`. I imagine it's more the text inside the `<p>` that does the wrapping and if the `<p>` had a border it would go under as well.

Comment: @DanGamble Hmm, seems to me that it's simply a matter of semantics, where those elements are placed in relation to each other; since the floated div is outside the toggled element.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Moving the floated element to be alongside the other items still causes the same problem. The structure is how it is atm as that's how i discovered the problem initially.

Comment: @DanGamble Have a look at this thread, I believe it pertains to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388623/css-why-block-element-wrap-around-floating-element

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks, the spec link hopefully clears it up. I'm guessing the text inside the `<p>` are themselves `inline` even though they don't have an element node which is why they wrap.

Comment: @DanGamble And also why you can still `text-align` them accordingly. Glad the link offered some insight!

Comment: I still don't understand the issue. Is the jsbin currently different from the jsbin you were originally describing? In your question you say that `display:table` is the solution to the problem, but the jsbin I'm looking at is problematic just because of the `display:table`; if you remove that it works great.